# Unusual condition expression in if statement

Tags: objective-c

```
- (IBAction)touchCardButton:(UIButton *)sender
{
   if ([sender.currentTitle length]) {

      UIImage *cardImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cardback"];
      [sender setBackgroundImage:cardImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

      [sender setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
      }
}
```

I understand that the if statement will continue if [sender.currentTitle length] is non-zero. However the syntax involved here is confusing me.

```
[sender currentTitle]
```

or in dot.syntax

```
sender.currentTitle
```

Is check the title of the button "sender". But what is length doing here? is length a method? does length return a value? Is it the equivalent of:

```
[[sender currentTitle] length]
```

Comment: I have searched apples documention everywhere btw

Comment: It's as usual as life, just checking the length of the title, if it's nin zero—move on. What's strange in it?

Comment: okay but what is length in this case? a message?

Comment: Of course it is, why don't you just check the docs? https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/length

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing unusual about this.

`sender.currentTitle` returns an NSString that is the title of the button. As you note, this is equivalent to `[sender currentTitle]`. In both cases, you are calling the `currentTitle` method on `sender`. Therefore, `[sender.currentTitle length]` calls the `length` method on the NSString that is the result of calling `currentTitle` on `sender` and returns an NSUInteger that is the string's length.

Another way of writing this is:

```
NSString *title = sender.currentTitle;
if ([title length] > 0) {
  // Do something if the length is not zero.
}
```

or to break it down even further:

```
NSString *title = sender.currentTitle;
NSUInteger length = [title length];
if (length > 0) {
  // Do something if the length is not zero.
}
```

If instead you just did this:

```
if ([sender currentTitle]) {
  // Do something if the string is not nil.
}
```

your conditional would be true if the button's currentTitle is not `nil`, which is **not** the same as having length > 0.

Comment: if NSClarification was a class itd return an integer of 1000000 for you! Thankyou. Perhaps the mixture of the dot syntax in the [] with the simplified method name of "length" has confused me.

Answer (score 0):

In Objective-C, the `.` is just syntactic sugar for calling the setter/getter, it's not a field accessor like it would be in Swift (does this question predates Swift?).

In your snippet, the getter for `currentTitle` is called and the `length` method is called on that string.